# Display Solr results based on custom selection

Tags: solr

I have a filed 'qualification' which is having multiple values (something like MCA, MBA, MSC, PhD, ...).

My requirement is to display results in the order `MSC, MCA, PhD, MBA`. So, I am using the below query to boost the field values.

```
&bq=(qualification: "MSC"^5 "MCA"^4 "PhD"^3 "MBA"^2)
```

The above query is working only when I use `q=*:*`

But when search with any text like `q=course`, I am not getting the results with specified order.

Please help what I did wrong.

Thanks & Regards
Venu

Answer (score 0):

You're probably not doing anything "wrong", but when you actually search for something, the score isn't flat (i.e. it's no longer just 1) any more.

If you don't want your query to affect the score, use a filter query (`fq` instead). This does however not give you any actual relevance inside the results - if you still want that, you'll probably have to adjust your boosts to be far higher, so that the actual scores are only used internally within each boost level.

```
&bq=qualification:"MSC"^50000
&bq=qualification:"MCA"^40000
&bq=qualification:"PhD"^30000 
&bq=qualification:"MBA"^20000
```

If you append `debugQuery=true` to your query string, you can see how the score is calculated for each document, and adjust your boosts accordingly.